# Was "something" written "some thing" around 1900 in United States?

Tags: spelling

I want to know whether words like: "something", "anything", "somewhat", etc., were written: "some thing", "any thing", "some what", around 1900 in United States.

I read a few letters of some historical importance and their author systematically splits the above mentioned words in two. He also writes "tomorrow" as "to-morrow", which was not a mistake, but about "something", "anything" and other similar words I do not know if he really intended writing them in two words or simply his ugly handwriting just gives the impression these words are written in two pieces.

Comment: Consider that both 'something' and 'some thing' are perfectly valid today, they would presumably be just as useful ~100 years ago.

Comment: So far as ***to-morrow*** is concerned, according to [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tomorrow%2Cto-morrow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctomorrow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20-%20morrow%3B%2Cc0) the non-hyphenated orthography didn't actually become *dominant* until the 1930s. But I'm doubtful that two-word ***some what*** (in the sense of "rather") was ever common (all citations in the full OED since 1200 have it as a single word).

Comment: Most of these basic compounds begin as two separate words and gradually hyphenate and then run together. The exact state of "something" at the turn of the 20th century in the US is probably a question for ELU.

Comment: We would need to see the phrase _in situ_ to determine whether the writer indended to write _something_ or was instead referring to one particular, or a few, things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1900s, *something* and *some thing* **were** used interchangeably, and today (for the most part) are still used interchangeably. If you used *some thing* instead of *something*, most people would never give it a second thought. **However**, as [this article](http://writingexplained.org/something-vs-some-thing-difference) explains, *some thing* is not a correct way to spell *something.* In fact, *some thing* means something entirely different.

From the article:

> *Something* is a **pronoun**. *Something* means an unspecified object or concept. It is a common word in both spoken and written English.

They explain that unlike other pronouns like *it* and *they*, *something* doesn't refer to anything specific.

Concerning *some thing*:

> Some writers divide the pronoun *something* into two words, forming the phrase *some thing.* This is not an accepted variant of this word. *Something* is a compound, and should **always** be spelled as a single word.

*Some thing* (in present-day English) would refer to *some* specific *thing*. as the article explains:

> That’s not to say that there are no contexts where *some* and *thing* might appear next to each other as separate words. *Some* is a **determiner**, and *thing* is a **noun**. The phrase *'some thing took hold of his ankle'* would not feel out of place in certain 19th century horror fiction.
>
> Today, though, a horror writer would probably include an *adjective*, to form *'some terrible thing'* or *'some unholy thing'*. Most people would also simply use the pronoun *something*.

So to sum up: in the 1900's, *some thing* and *something* were synonymous. Nowadays, *some thing* **only** refers to **some specific thing**, giving it a much more literal connotation.

Comment: And as @FumbleFingers pointed out, 'to-morrow', while a bit archaic, is still an acceptable variant of the word _tomorrow_.